# How can I define vim syntax folding for Informix 4GL source code?

Tags: vim, code-folding

I use vim to edit Informix 4GL source code which has this sort of syntax:

```
FUNCTION
  FOR ...
  ...
  END FOR
END FUNCTION
```

I wish to fold the functions using za zM etc

This works

```
  :set foldmarker=FUNCTION,END\ FUNCTION
  :set foldmethod=marker
```

However the keywords can also be in lower case and I'd ideally also like to fold MAIN..END MAIN, so markers are not able to do this.

I tried

```
:syn region myFun start="FUNCTION" end="END FUNCTION" transparent fold
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

but it had no effect. I already have a syntax file that does color highlighting and `:syn` showed `myFun` included in the syntax definitions.

How can I configure case-independent syntax folding of FUNCTION...END FUNCTION and MAIN..END MAIN ?

---

Update: I have tried http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2287 but it has some problems:

- It folds at a level of detail I don't want (`IF`, `FOR`, `WHILE`, ...)
- It assumes `END` statements start on a new line (so `IF a<b call c() END IF` folds to EOF)
- It thinks `SELECT * FROM table \n FOR UPDATE` is the start of a `FOR` statement

So I'd like to try creating something much simpler first.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Informix 4GL. I have found a syntax file for it but it folds more than I want (IF statements), has bugs (e.g. when "END IF" on same line as "IF", or counts "SELECT * FROM table FOR UPDATE" as start of FOR loop) and doesn't fold FUNCTION! (though the file seems to have code for folding functions)

Comment: Did you try `set foldmethod=indent`?

Comment: @romainl: I hadn't but I have now. It's not ideal for me but it is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should define your own folding function, that way you will have more control over what is folded when. The following fold function folds `function`/`end function` case insensitively, and should be fairly easy to adjust for further requirements:

```
function! InformixFold()
  let line      = getline(v:lnum)
  let prev_line = getline(v:lnum-1)

  if match(line, '^\s*function\s*$') >= 0
    return 1
  elseif match(prev_line, '^\s*end\s*function\s*$') >= 0
    return 0
  else
    return "="
endfunction
```

Then set `foldmethod` to `expr` and `foldexpr` to the function:

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=InformixFold()
```

See `help fold-expr` for more.

"Screenshot":

```
- FUNCTION
|   FOR ...
|   ...
|   END FOR
| END FUNCTION

+ +--  5 lines: FUNCTION------------------------------------------------------
```